# Портирование на мобильное приложение

Tags: python, opencv, mobile-development

Мне хотелось бы портировать программу для консоли на python на мобильное приложение. Проблема в том что я совсем не разбираюсь в программировании для мобильных приложений. Хотелось бы услышать насколько сложно это реализовать и как много времени это займёт. Код прикладываю ниже:

```
import io
import cv2
import time
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as plt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 1280)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 720)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS, 30)
x, y, w, h = 550, 250, 100, 100
cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(r'C:\Users\srsc1\Desktop\haarcascades\haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
heartbeat_count = 128
heartbeat_values = [0]*heartbeat_count
heartbeat_times = [time.time()]*heartbeat_count
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

while(True):    
    ret, frame = cap.read() 
    img = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = cascade.detectMultiScale(img, scaleFactor = 1.5, minNeighbors = 5, minSize= (20, 20))
    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
        face_dec = cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (255, 0 , 0), 2)
        #Заменить crop_img на алгоритм отслеживания лица(по каскаду) = img[y:y + h, x:x + w]
        heartbeat_values = heartbeat_values[1:] + [np.average(face_dec)]
        heartbeat_times = heartbeat_times[1:] + [time.time()]
        #Функции графика
        ax.plot(heartbeat_times, heartbeat_values)
        fig.canvas.draw()
        plot_img_np = np.fromstring(fig.canvas.tostring_rgb(), dtype=np.uint8, sep='')
        plot_img_np = plot_img_np.reshape(fig.canvas.get_width_height()[::-1] + (3,))
        plt.cla()
        #Показ фрейма
        cv2.imshow('Main', img )
        cv2.imshow('Graph', plot_img_np)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
           break
    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Так же хотелось бы добавить что для портирования в мобильную среду разработки у меня есть всего 5 дней, так как мой проект участвует в важном для меня конкурсе 13го числа. Поэтому ответ важен как можно скорее, стоит ли тратить на это своё время или нет?

Comment: Скорее всего займёт это в описанных вами условиях никак не меньше недели. Скорее всего вам стоит рассмотреть фриланс биржи, т.к. тут надо много отдельных вопросов задавать, надеясь что найдутся спецы со свободным временем, что маловероятно, т.к. спецов по мобилкам на питоне почти не существует в природе.